# Non-Unicode characters get changed to "????" when stored to MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, sql, unicode

I am creating a web application around tweets fetched from the Twitter REST API. I am facing an issue where non-unicode characters like Korean, Chinese, and other Asian languages are displayed correctly when printed in the python console, but when I store it to a SQL database the string values get changed to "????? ???" or the likes of that.

I am using the Twython module, and this is my code for fetching the tweets, which works correctly and when I print the tweets it displays those characters correctly

```
from twython import Twython
import json
APP_KEY= 'abcdfefdags'
APP_SECRET = 'abcdefghdfa'
SEARCH_QUERY='russia'
SEARCH_COUNT= 3
twitter = Twython(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, oauth_version=2)
ACCESS_TOKEN = twitter.obtain_access_token()
twitter1 = Twython(APP_KEY, access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN)

def getTweetQuery():
    return SEARCH_QUERY

def getTweetTextDict():
    tweetTempList = []
    data = []
    listOfTweets = dict()
    data = twitter1.search(q=SEARCH_QUERY, count=SEARCH_COUNT)  
    for x in range(0,SEARCH_COUNT):
        tweetData = dict()
        s = (data['statuses'][x]['text']) 
        tweetData['text'] = s
        s = (data['statuses'][x]['created_at'])
        tweetData['created_at'] = s
        s = (data['statuses'][x]['user']['name'])
        tweetData['name'] = s
        s = (data['statuses'][x]['user']['profile_image_url'])
        tweetData['profile_image_url'] = s
        listOfTweets[x] = tweetData
    return listOfTweets
```

Here is the code when I store those to an SQL database

```
import mysql.connector
from firstsite.website import twit
class SQLDataSystem:
    def insertNewTweets(self):
        cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='djangouser', password='1234',
                              host='127.0.0.1',
                              database='django_db')

        cursor = cnx.cursor()                                                            
        dataPacket = twit.getTweetTextDict()

        dataPacketLength = len(dataPacket.keys())
        for x in range (0, dataPacketLength):
            tweet = dataPacket[x]['text']
            tweetTime = dataPacket[x]['created_at']
            twitterName = dataPacket[x]['name']
            twitterPicture = dataPacket[x]['profile_image_url']
            add_tweet = ("INSERT INTO website_tweets " +
                         "(tweet, tweetTime, twitterName, twitterPicture) "+
                         "VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s)")
            arguments = (tweet, tweetTime, twitterName, twitterPicture)
            cursor.execute(add_tweet, arguments)
            cnx.commit()
```

when I check the database via

```
SELECT * FROM website_tweets;
```

as well as retrieving it and printing it via Python, a string which might've said
'@nytvideo @@KOREA:왜 이 테러리스트들은 구속하지 않나요??' 
turns into
'@nytvideo @@KOREA:? ? ??????? ???? ?????'
How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Use a different collation, one that supports those characters?

Comment: Have you looked into manually encoding the characters as ASCII, then saving that string?

Comment: "manually encoding the characters as ASCII"? That sentence doesn't make sense. ASCII doesn't have representation for korean characters. The likely reasons here is that either the database doesn't support the characters (wrong collation, as @RobertHarvey already pointed out), the strings aren't stored as unicode in Python either, the SQL framework doesn't support unicode strings, or it's the output of the strings to verify their contents that is wrong. There *plenty* of ways this can go wrong. Text is not easy.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen The strings do get printed out correctly before it goes through SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 things that needs checking are:

1. Collation of the DB - you need it to be UTF8 and not Latin1 or something else.
2. In the connection itself - `use_unicode=True`
3. Make sure that your unicode strings don't accidentally get converted to normal strings (formatting has a tendency to do that)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your script, but the database settings.
Have a look to 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/faqs-cjk.html#qandaitem-A-11-1-2